# Calendar Module: Calendar block with mini-calendar to show next month instead of current

Tags: views, blocks, datetime

I am using the Calendar module (http://drupal.org/project/calendar).

One of the default block  (called **Block**) in the Calendar module gives you the option to embed a mini-calendar as a block on your site. I would like this mini-calendar to show a future month instead of current month.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: usually this block has a view controlling its output, try checking that view first.

Comment: @saadlulu I did. I could not find anything to there that allowed me to adjust the month displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the Contextual Filter for this block. Instead of providing a default value of "Current date" you can set it to "PHP Code" and use the following:

```
return date('Y-m',strtotime('+1 month'));
```

[image: Screenshot of contextual filter]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is still actual. Just change date in contextual filter WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE Provide default value to Y-m format (PHP - return '2014-02', Fixed value - 2014-02).